# reading a pcap file in c++

Tags: c++, header, pcap

I want to read a pcap file and get the header information of the packets of a flow...

for this I found a c++ program from http://www.cnblogs.com/xiangshancuizhu/archive/2012/10/14/2723654.html  which read the pcap file and have a header pointer , this  pointer

class just point to length of header, but I want to access the other features of header

such as syn,fin,ack,seq no,....here is my code, how can I do this?

```
 char errbuff[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

/*
* Step 4 - Open the file and store result in pointer to pcap_t
*/

// Use pcap_open_offline
// http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_41b5/html/group__wpcapfunc.html#g91078168a13de8848df2b7b83d1f5b69
pcap_t * pcap = pcap_open_offline(file.c_str(), errbuff);

/*
* Step 5 - Create a header and a data object
*/

// Create a header object:
// http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/structpcap__pkthdr.html
struct pcap_pkthdr *header;

// Create a character array using a u_char
// u_char is defined here:
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\WinSock2.h
// typedef unsigned char   u_char;
const u_char *data;

/*
* Step 6 - Loop through packets and print them to screen
*/
u_int packetCount = 0;
while (int returnValue = pcap_next_ex(pcap, &header, &data) >= 0)
{
    // Print using printf. See printf reference:
    // http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

    // Show the packet number
    printf("Packet # %i\n", ++packetCount);

    // Show the size in bytes of the packet
    printf("Packet size: %d bytes\n", header->len);
```

and header is a structure like:

```
struct pcap_pkthdr {
    struct timeval ts;  /* time stamp */
    bpf_u_int32 caplen; /* length of portion present */
    bpf_u_int32 len;    /* length this packet (off wire) */
};
```

and I want this structure have more members, what should I do?
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You can't add more fields to pcap_pkthdr - libpcap won't do anything with those fields.  Packet *data* fields, such as the link-layer, IP, and TCP headers, are *NOT* features of that header.

The packet data is pointed to by the `data` variable.  *That's* where the link-layer header is, where the IP header is in IP packets, where the TCP header is in TCP packets, and so on.  See, for example, [Tim Carstens' tutorial on how to use libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html).

You might want to look at building your program using [libcrafter](http://code.google.com/p/libcrafter/), which is "a high level library for C++ designed to make easier the creation and decoding of network packets".  You may not be interested in the "crafting" part, but would be interested in the "decoding" part.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, I read this library and as I said I want to access the flag bits, as I see in this library function it can get me the flag, the output is like this:                          < TCP (20 bytes) :: SrcPort = 0 , DstPort = 80 , SeqNumber = 0 , AckNumber = 0 , DataOffset = 5 , Reserved = 0 , Flags = ( ) , WindowsSize = 5840 , CheckSum = 0x0 , UrgPointer = 0 , >
but how can I use the flag, and find the SIN or FIN in the tcp packet?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a pcap file (without using any external lib to read pcap file) you need to parse that file according to the format which is something like this

**GLOBAL_HEADER | PACKET_HEADER |PACKET_DATA | PACKET_HEADER |PACKET_DATA|....**

Read global header and after that, you parse data in a loop till file ends.
You must know the proper format  and your structures must be correct

for this, you can follow this link 
https://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html  **UDP Header is not mentioned in the link